# Bind custom event to dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been binding events to dynamically created elements without any kind of issues by using:

```
$(document).on(event, element, function)
```

Now I want to bind a custom event and I just can´t get it to work.

The event is a JS plugin to handle single e double click. If I use it like this:

```
$('#test').oneordoubleclick({
    oneclick: function () {
        alert('you have clicked this node.');
    },
    dblclick: function () {
        alert('you have double clicked this node.');
    }
});
```

It works like a charm, but, as I transform the code to bind the event to dynamically created elements, like this:

```
$(document).on('oneordoubleclick', '#test', {
    oneclick: function () {
        alert('you have clicked this node.');
    },
    dblclick: function () {
        alert('you have double clicked this node.');
    }
});
```

It stops working!

It wasn't supposed to work? What am i doing wrong? It is possible to do what i want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, `.oneordoubleclick` is not an Event, just like `.footable` or `.tooltip`. Therefore, you cannot put it in `$(document).on("oneordoubleclick","#test", ...)`

Here's my solution, with the aid of the plugin source code:

```
// Custom functions
let singleClick = function () { // your function when is single click
    alert('you have clicked this node.');
}

let doubleClick = function () { // your function when is double click
    alert('you have double clicked this node.');
}

// Necessary to differentiate is single or double click
let timer,
    do_click = function (e, fx) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            fx();
        }, 400); // if there is no another click between 0.4s, then it is single click
    },
    do_dblclick = function (e, fx) {
        clearTimeout(timer); // the single click function will not be called
        fx();
    };

// Listener
$(document) .on("click",    "#test", function (e) { do_click(e, singleClick) })
            .on("dblclick", "#test", function (e) { do_dblclick(e, doubleClick) })
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answer, i needed to know which DOM element was responsible for the call. To achieve that i changed a little bit XH栩恒 answer code...

```
// Necessary to differentiate is single or double click
let timer,
    do_click = function (e, fx, element) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            fx(element);
        }, 400); // if there is no another click between 0.4s, then it is single click
    },
    do_dblclick = function (e, fx, element) {
        clearTimeout(timer); // the single click function will not be called
        fx(element);
    };


// Listener
$(document).on("click", ".teste", function (e) {
        do_click(e, singleClick, $(this))
    })
    .on("dblclick", ".teste", function (e) {
        do_dblclick(e, doubleClick, $(this))
    })

let singleClick = function (element) { // your function when is single click
    console.log(element)
}

let doubleClick = function (element) { // your function when is double click
    console.log(element)
}
```